# How to emit an custom event in socket.io?

Tags: swift, websocket, socket.io

this is the first time I work with socket. I'm creating a chat feature that connect from my app to the server. I tried a couple ways but nothing works. I connect my app with socket/ Websocket successfully but I emit but not getting return data from server.

```
let SocketURL:String = "https://apps.abc.com:8080"
let WSSSocketURL:String = "wss://apps.abc.com:8080"
var conversationID:Int = 0
var socket:SocketIOClient?
var socketManager:SocketManager?
var otherChatUser:ChatUser = ChatUser()
var messageList:[ChatMessage] = [ChatMessage]()
var NumberOfSection:Int = 2

func setupSocket() -> Void {
    socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: SocketURL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    self.socket = socketManager?.defaultSocket

    socketManager?.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral:   .connectParams(["token": KeychainService.getWssToken() as Any, "EIO" : 3]),
                        .path("/wss"))

    self.socket!.connect()

    self.socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) {
        data, ack in

        self.con_create()
    }

}

func con_create() -> Void {
    self.socketManager?.engine?.ws?.connect()
    self.socketManager?.engine?.ws?.onConnect = {

        let JsonData = [ "user" : self.otherChatUser.AuthID ]
        self.socket?.emit("con_create", JsonData)

        // expect to get back the conversation ID from the server after socket.on
        self.socket?.on("con_create") {
            (data, ack) in
            print("con_create")
            let json = data[1] as? JSON
            self.conversationID = json!["id"].intValue
        }
    }
}
```

self.conversationID should be a whole number like 16 or 15.